# IF Formula to serve multiple scenarios

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, excel-formula, nested

I`m looking for a formula to serve the followings
**A, B, C & D** are dates
if **C** falls between **A & B** then **"ok"**,
if not then **"OK-Overdue"**,
if **C** blank and **D>B** then **"under-review"**
if **C** blank and **D<B** then **"Pending"**

**D** will be always **Today()**

Comment: Have you tried using `IF` and `AND` yet?

Comment: Vlookup() with a list.

Answer (score 1):

It was a bit unclear I must admit, the formula's result will be in another cell, let's say **E**.

I am assuming that A is always smaller than B. As in, A is start date, B is end date.

```
=IF(AND(A1<C1;C1<B1);"OK";"OK-Overdue")
```

This will work, but not when C is blank. Let's check that first:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C1);"BLANK";IF(AND(A1<C1;C1<B1);"OK";"OK-Overdue"))
```

Okay, and we didn't want to print "BLANK" when it's blank, we want to make further checks. Let's make the

> if C blank and D>B then "under-review" if C blank and D<B then "Pending"

check first, then we just replace "BLANK" in the formula we have done so far. Okay, let's do the D/B-checks:

```
=IF(B1<D1;"under-review";"Pending")
```

**Okay, finally let's put that in the "BLANK"-space, and here it is...**

### Final Result:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C1);IF(B1<D1;"under-review";"Pending");IF(AND(A1<C1;C1<B1);"OK";"OK-Overdue"))
```

Hope it works like you want it to, just let me know if something's off. **NOTE:** I don't check if D=B. So if D=B, it will say "Pending". :)

Comment: Thanks,  it worked quite good :)

Comment: Glad to hear! If you found my answer to be the solution to your problem, please accept my answer as the solution by pressing the check-mark. Have a nice day! :)